# mysql_real_escape_string , htmlspecialchars mistake?

Tags: php

I know `htmlspecialchars` is for html output and `mysql_real_escape_string` is for insert for the database.  I'm not sure how to apply in this scenario.  For example

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_GET['search'],ENT_QUOTES));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('','$search')",$this->connect);

echo "<a href='http://www.example.com/$search'>$search</a>";
```

Do i have to seperate the top line so `mysql_real_escape_string` is before the insert and `htmlspecialchars` is after?  I'm hoping i don't have to otherwise i have to go over alot of code..

Also would using `htmlspecialchars` twice do anything different then once?  I'm sure somewhere in my code i have used `htmlspecialchars` twice on the same variable.

e.g.

```
$var = htmlspecialchars($one); //top of page

$var2 = htmlspecialchars($var); //another function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['search'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerm) . ')"', $this->connect);

echo "<a href='http://www.example.com/" . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($searchTerm), ENT_QUOTES) . "'>$search</a>";
```

Only escape at the exact moment needed, once. In your case, since the value is supposed to be part of a URL, it needs to be URL encoded. Since that URL is then made part of HTML, it needs to be HTML escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You need two copies of the search variable: one to be stored in SQL, and that one you can pass through mysql_real_escape_string; the other to be displayed, and there you use htmlspecialchars.

Actually you need three copies: in one, you encode e.g. " " to "+" and this is for GET URLs; another will escape SQL characters; and the third will escape HTML.

You may want to pass _web and _sql through UTF8, too.

```
$search_web = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search'],ENT_QUOTES);
$search_sql = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
$search_url = urlencode($_GET['search']);

// Do try and upgrade to PDO, here...
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('','$search_sql')",$this->connect);

echo "<a href='http://www.example.com/$search_url'>$search_web</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape string for sql (※do not escape html special chars).

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
```

Use `htmlspecialchars` when you display the data in web page.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var) // ex. $var is the content of $_GET['search'] ?>
```